# Inclusion of polytopes

Tags: ds.algorithms, linear-algebra, linear-programming, computational-geometry

Consider the following two system of linear (in)eqaulities:

$S = Ax \leq b;\; Cx = e$

$T = Dx \leq d;\; Gx = g$

How can I check if $S\cap \neg T=\emptyset$ where $\neg T$ is the complement of the linear system $T$.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/q/219057/35417 "Testing if a point is inside a convex polytope formed by halfspaces in n-dimension" is different but related

Comment: Your question has been answered here: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32587/checking-equivalence-of-two-polytopes/32589#32589

Comment: @ChristophHaase, did you find a source that this problem is $\Pi_2^P$-hard?

Comment: I do not see the connection of the proposed source to my problem. Could you please clarify it more?

Comment: @ChristophHaase, did you find a source that this problem is ΠP2-hard?

Comment: You are asking for an algorithm to check whether a polytope $T$ is included (for usual set inclusion) in another polytope $S$.
It does not look like a research-level question to me. Or you need to be more specific: are you rather interested in the complexity, as your comment suggests?